# Gmapping for indoor aerial vehicle?

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I would like to combine gmapping for indoor aerial vehicle.
Something similar as http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/blog/node/152
However, I think they used custom Gmapping, not a stack on ROS.
Clear path to achieve will be

Subscribe IMU to correct laser scans with respect to attitude.
Subscribe height from some sensor (sonar, laser).
Provide corrected information to gmapping.

If there is an implementation to do this, it would be great to know that.
If it is not, it is good to know that how to provide height information to gmapping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30753/gmapping-for-indoor-aerial-vehicle?/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-03-29**:
You might want to check hector_quadrotor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The names of this package have changed, now they are:

- [https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping](http://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping)
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapping
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapping

---

Originally posted by [Stéphane Magnenat](https://answers.ros.org/users/1250/st%C3%A9phane-magnenat/) with karma: 83 on 2013-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0